# override \scshape in fancyhdr

Tags: fonts, titles, fancyhdr, typography

I would like to be able to disable the `\scshape` for a specific word in the title of a subsection. For example when using `$\mathfrak{}$`.

Here is the parameters I have set for the layout.

`\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\fontsize{7}{11}\selectfont \scshape \rightmark}`

Thank you very much!

EDIT

Here is an example:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{report}

% Packages used
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm, amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\space}{}} 
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.2pt}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\fontsize{7}{11}\selectfont \scshape \rightmark}
\fancyhead[LO,RE]{\fontsize{7}{11}\selectfont \scshape \leftmark}
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}

\begin{document}
\section{$\mathfrak{sl}_2$}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\scshape` does not affect the math fonts at all.

Comment: You might try \mathrm{} or \mathtt{}

Comment: It is _always_ much easier to understand the question if you provide a complete small document from `\documentclass` to `\end{document}` that demonstrates the issue. As it stands it is hard to guess what your question means.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle It does in this case. Yes, but it is just using the above layout with a title containing some $\mathfrak{}$. I will edit the question to add a minimal example.

Comment: then you have something _very_ strange in your local font set up and it's not possible to comment on code you haven't shown.

Comment: @JohnKormylo None work. Thank you for trying :)

Comment: Are you sure your heading isn't been uppercased (rather than just set with scshape? that would affect maths,

Comment: report class uses `\def\sectionmark##1{%
      \markright {\MakeUppercase{%
        \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\z@
` so the mark is uppercased, the `\textsc` font doesn't affect the maths. You can hide the math in a macro that you `\protect` or you could use tehe `textcase` package to redefine `\MakeUppercase` so it skips math

Comment: Never done this before but I will try and come back if I don't succeed. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Thank you for your package too! Should you just mention this as an answer so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`\textsc` is not related to the issue. The mark is uppercased using `\makeUppercse`.

the `textcase` package has an option to redefine this command to make it equal to is `\MakeTextUppercase` command which automatically skips math mode.

So adding

```
\usepackage[overload]{textcase}
```

keeps all math in the heading lowercase